# trouble of python rds connection to aws rds with ssh tunneling

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-rds, tunnel

I have code for connect rds database with ssh tunneling as follows
but I have stuck to connect after making tunnel.
someone can help me?
hmm.. the tunnel is successfulling made. but stucked in connection.
logs are as  follows after code.help!!!!!!
and additional information the pem file as used now for DBeaver.

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('15.164.xxx.xxx',22),  # SSH host and port
        ssh_username='ec2-user',  # SSH user_name
        ssh_pkey='key-stg-evchg-xxxxxxxxxx.pem',
        remote_bind_address=('rds-stg-evchg-cluster.cluster-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com', 3306)) as tunnel:
    print(tunnel)

    conn = pymysql.connect(
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
        user="user",
        password="password"
    )
```

### follows is tunnel information

```
<class 'sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder'> object
ssh gateway: 15.164.xxx.xxx:22
proxy: no
username: ec2-user
authentication: {'pkeys': [('ssh-rsa', b'7295dd6621412412312312fedf')]}
hostkey: not checked
status: started
keepalive messages: every 5.0 sec
tunnel connection check: disabled
concurrent connections: allowed
compression: not requested
logging level: ERROR
local binds: [('0.0.0.0', 0)]
remote binds: [('rds-stg-evchg-cluster.cluster-cvrtu5pd6rrl.xxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com', 3306)]
```

Comment: Can you try reading the key as below instead   ssh_pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(path to pem)

Comment: unfortunatly, it's no effect to this code, thank you anyway. TT